# Compute multiple column to column differences R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to compute differences among several columns, per identifiers (see script below for reproducible example and target data frame).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246166/r-identifying-column-pairs-and-computing-the-differences) is somehow similar, but only for pairs of identifiers. I can't think on how to adapt it.
I could also have several data frame, one per identifier, but I also don't know in that case how to compute multiple columns differences.

The code below allows to create a sample dataset, and has the code I currently use. It gives me what I want, I'd just like to know if there is a way not to spell out all the differences I want to compute (in my dataset, I have more parameters and depths than in that sample data).

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
library(tidyverse)
# sample data
create.dt <-  function(t = 0) {
   data.frame(parameter = rep(c("temperature","oxygen"), each = 3),
                  date = rep(c(Sys.Date()+t), each = 6),
                  depth = rep(1:3, times = 2),
             value = c(data.frame(x = rnorm(3, 16, 2)) %>% 
                         arrange(-x) %>% pull,
                       data.frame(x = rnorm(3, 7, 1)) %>% 
                         arrange(-x) %>% pull
                  ))
  
  }

# Multi-site dataset
dt <- rbind(
  cbind(site = "A", create.dt(t = c(-3:0))),
  cbind(site = "B", create.dt(t = c(-3:0))),
  cbind(site = "C", create.dt(t = c(-3:0))),
  cbind(site = "D", create.dt(t = c(-3:0))),
  cbind(site = "E", create.dt(t = c(-3:0))))

# Reshape the data and compute differences
dt %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = c(site,date), names_from = c(parameter,depth), values_from = value, names_sep = "_") %>%
  # do the difference, depth to depth, parameter by parameter
  # What I would like is not have to write manually each differences pair
  mutate(temperature_1_2 = temperature_1 - temperature_2,
         temperature_1_3 = temperature_1 - temperature_3,
         temperature_2_3 = temperature_2 - temperature_3,
         oxygen_1_2 = oxygen_1 - oxygen_2,
         oxygen_1_3 = oxygen_1 - oxygen_3,
         oxygen_2_3 = oxygen_2 - oxygen_3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

create.dt <-  function(t = 0) {
  data.frame(parameter = rep(c("temperature","oxygen"), each = 3),
             date = rep(c(Sys.Date()+t), each = 6),
             depth = rep(1:3, times = 2),
             value = c(data.frame(x = rnorm(3, 16, 2)) %>% 
                         arrange(-x) %>% pull,
                       data.frame(x = rnorm(3, 7, 1)) %>% 
                         arrange(-x) %>% pull
             ))
  
}

# Multi-site dataset
dt <- rbind(
  cbind(site = "A", create.dt(t = c(-3:0))),
  cbind(site = "B", create.dt(t = c(-3:0))),
  cbind(site = "C", create.dt(t = c(-3:0))),
  cbind(site = "D", create.dt(t = c(-3:0))),
  cbind(site = "E", create.dt(t = c(-3:0))))

# result

temperature <- str_c("temperature_", 1:3)
oxygen <- str_c("oxygen_", 1:3)

temperature_frml <- combn(temperature, m = 2, FUN = function(x) str_c(x, collapse = " - ")) 
oxygen_frml <- combn(oxygen, m = 2, FUN = function(x) str_c(x, collapse = " - ")) 
all_frml <- c(temperature_frml, oxygen_frml)

df_wider <- dt %>% pivot_wider(
  id_cols = c(site, date),
  names_from = c(parameter, depth),
  values_from = value,
  names_sep = "_"
)

bind_cols(df_wider,
          map_dfc(
            .x = all_frml,
            .f = ~ transmute(.data = df_wider,!!.x :=  eval(parse_expr(.x)))
          ))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 14
#>    site  date       temperature_1 temperature_2 temperature_3 oxygen_1 oxygen_2
#>    <chr> <date>             <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 A     2021-12-11          17.6          17.1          12.9     7.34     6.86
#>  2 A     2021-12-12          17.6          17.1          12.9     7.34     6.86
#>  3 A     2021-12-13          17.6          17.1          12.9     7.34     6.86
#>  4 A     2021-12-14          17.6          17.1          12.9     7.34     6.86
#>  5 B     2021-12-11          17.1          15.6          13.7     8.52     7.58
#>  6 B     2021-12-12          17.1          15.6          13.7     8.52     7.58
#>  7 B     2021-12-13          17.1          15.6          13.7     8.52     7.58
#>  8 B     2021-12-14          17.1          15.6          13.7     8.52     7.58
#>  9 C     2021-12-11          17.7          15.5          13.6     7.66     7.31
#> 10 C     2021-12-12          17.7          15.5          13.6     7.66     7.31
#> 11 C     2021-12-13          17.7          15.5          13.6     7.66     7.31
#> 12 C     2021-12-14          17.7          15.5          13.6     7.66     7.31
#> 13 D     2021-12-11          16.5          16.4          14.5     7.50     7.27
#> 14 D     2021-12-12          16.5          16.4          14.5     7.50     7.27
#> 15 D     2021-12-13          16.5          16.4          14.5     7.50     7.27
#> 16 D     2021-12-14          16.5          16.4          14.5     7.50     7.27
#> 17 E     2021-12-11          16.7          16.1          15.7     7.52     7.51
#> 18 E     2021-12-12          16.7          16.1          15.7     7.52     7.51
#> 19 E     2021-12-13          16.7          16.1          15.7     7.52     7.51
#> 20 E     2021-12-14          16.7          16.1          15.7     7.52     7.51
#> # ... with 7 more variables: oxygen_3 <dbl>,
#> #   temperature_1 - temperature_2 <dbl>, temperature_1 - temperature_3 <dbl>,
#> #   temperature_2 - temperature_3 <dbl>, oxygen_1 - oxygen_2 <dbl>,
#> #   oxygen_1 - oxygen_3 <dbl>, oxygen_2 - oxygen_3 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>